# Error in your MYSQL syntax: Where

Tags: php, mysql

I have trouble when using commands WHERE in the following php script

```
$sql = "SELECT t.nama, b.nama, k.nama, r.program, r.rka1, b.kode, r.tahun FROM rka1 r 
LEFT JOIN tahun t ON r.tahun=t.tahun 
LEFT JOIN komisi k ON r.komisi=k.komisi 
LEFT JOIN bidang b ON r.bidang=b.bidang 
ORDER BY r.tahun, r.bidang, r.komisi, r.rka1 
WHERE r.komisi=$komisi";
```

always appears an error message as follows:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE r.komisi=20' at line 6

is there who can explain my mistake, thank you for your response

Comment: put order by at last

Comment: Yes .. you are right, thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT t.nama, b.nama, k.nama, r.program, r.rka1, b.kode, r.tahun FROM rka1 r 
LEFT JOIN tahun t ON r.tahun=t.tahun 
LEFT JOIN komisi k ON r.komisi=k.komisi 
LEFT JOIN bidang b ON r.bidang=b.bidang 
WHERE r.komisi=$komisi
ORDER BY r.tahun, r.bidang, r.komisi, r.rka1 
";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$sql = "SELECT t.nama, b.nama, k.nama, r.program, r.rka1, b.kode, r.tahun FROM rka1 r 
    LEFT JOIN tahun t ON r.tahun=t.tahun 
    LEFT JOIN komisi k ON r.komisi=k.komisi 
    LEFT JOIN bidang b ON r.bidang=b.bidang 
    WHERE r.komisi={$komisi}
    ORDER BY r.tahun, r.bidang, r.komisi, r.rka1";
```

I just wrapped your `$komisi` variable with curly brackets. If the value of  `$komisi` is a string, you can add single quotes around it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You have missed syntax error. `where` clause should be before `ORDER BY`

Comment: oh yes! haven't spotted that one. I'll update my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple format of MYSQL SELECT query

```
SELECT [fields] FROM [table name] WHERE [condition] ORDER BY [fields] GROUP BY [fields]
```

[**Read More**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-select-query.htm)

Please use `where` before `ORDER BY`.

```
$sql = "SELECT t.nama, b.nama, k.nama, r.program, r.rka1, b.kode, r.tahun 
   FROM rka1 r 
   LEFT JOIN tahun t ON r.tahun=t.tahun 
   LEFT JOIN komisi k ON r.komisi=k.komisi 
   LEFT JOIN bidang b ON r.bidang=b.bidang 
WHERE r.komisi=$komisi
ORDER BY r.tahun, r.bidang, r.komisi, r.rka1 ";
```